Using Japanese characters in NUXT 3 URL
I am working on a nuxt blog and ran into an issue.
I am using the markdown feature where the blog is generated from markdown files but it does not seem to work with Japanese text.
For example, if I have markdown like this:
blog (folder)

post01.md
ポースト０１.md

Then they will both show up in the list with links like this:
<NuxtLink :to="blog.path" class="">

Gives us:
<a href="/blog/post01" class="">Post01<a>

and
<a href="/blog/ポースト０１" class="">ポースト０１<a>

while:
<NuxtLink :to="encodeURIComponent(post.path)" class="">

Gives us:
<a href="/blog/post01" class="">post01</a>

and
<a href="/blog/%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%EF%BC%90%EF%BC%91" class="">ポースト０１<a>

In either case, the English link works and the Japanese one goes to a 404 (The 404 URL is http://localhost:3000/blog/ポースト０１).
Is there some way I can make the link work or can I only have ascii character links?
Note: I am using the i18n plugin, but not for routing.
If this is something I should make a request to fix, should I ask the NUXT people or the markdown plugin people?

That definitely sounds like a bug. I’d guess that you could try filing the bug with the markdown plugin, see what they say, and escalate to NUXT if they don’t respond or they tell you it isn’t their problem.

Thanks to the comment from @nneonneo I went to the issues site for the content plug in and found this was a common issue. Apparently, they use slugify to get the file names which strips non ascii characters.
The fix is surprising, add a _path option to the front matter in the markdown file:
---
title: 'ポースト０１'
_path: "ポースト０１"
---

# Title
Page content here.

Will use the _path instead of the file name and it won't be filtered.
https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/1383#issuecomment-1196237686
